# Vim autocommand to insert text not working

Tags: vim

**UPDATE**

Turned out I was using a wrong local leader... It is defined as "\\" in my vimrc, so I typed \\dc, but vim mapped \dc instead...

---

I am trying to write an autocommand that will create a normal mode mapping depending on the file type. When executed, the mapping would insert a simple `print` statement which varies depending on the language (useful for debugging).

This is what I currently have:

```
augroup debugging
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType c nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>db Oprintf("Debugging");<esc>
augroup END
```

My local leader is set to "\\" (`let maplocalleader = "\\"`). However, the mapping is not set when I open a C file (`.c`).

File type is `on` in my `vimrc`.

Is my autocmd badly written?

Comment: Your snippet looks and works fine for me. Check the filetype and mapping: `:setl filetype?` and `:nmap <localleader>db`.

Comment: Thanks to `:nmap <localleader>db` I found that my local leader is `\` and not `\\\`. Should I delete the post?

Comment: Well, there are worse questions kept here. Let me write a quick answer and accept it for posterity; it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the actual mapleader used via

```
:nmap <localleader>db
```

It should list your mapping (in a buffer where `:setl filetype?` yields `c`).

Also note that the string `"\\"` resolves to a **single backslash** due to Vim's string expression rules. To get a double backslash, use single quotes `'\\'` or double the backslashes `"\\\\"`.